# How to generate random number of given decimal point between 2 number in Python?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random number with 1 decimal point between min_time and m_time, like 0.3

Now I have a really quirk solution

```
m_time = 0.5
min_time = 0.2
float(randint(int(min_time * 10), int(m_time * 10))) / 10
```

it works, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the preferred way is to [uniformly](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform) choose a floating number between `min_time` and `max_time` and then use the built-in [round](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) function (to the first decimal place):

```
round(random.uniform(min_time, max_time), 1)
```

Comment: How could I not think about this simple solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
import decimal
import random
```

-- i and j belong your limit like 2 and 3

```
decimal.Decimal('%d.%d' % (random.randint(0,i),random.randint(0,j)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you have is pretty ok. Although you could also write it like this

```
0.1*randint(int(min_time * 10), int(m_time * 10))
```

The other obvious option is

```
round(random.random()*(m_time-min_time)+min_time, 1)
```